# create custom constant suffix in C#

Tags: c#, .net

i am trying to develop a class for unlimited size integer values, all i need is to
make a new custom constant suffix used with the assign operator.

For example:

lets assume the class name is BigInt and the Suffix created is B

the assign statement will be like this

```
// B character will tell the compiler about the New Data Type
BigInt x = 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111B;
```

is there any way to achieve this?

Special Regards

Comment: Any reason you can't simply use the existing [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) structure?

Comment: Nope, that's not possible unless you want to make your own C# compiler.  I'd suggest simply `new BigInt("111")`, which is likely all your literal would have compiled to.

Answer (score 7):

No. The language / compiler do not support this. Something close, which you might want to look into is an implicit [conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx). That would let you do something like this:

```
BigInt b = "1234";

public class BigInt
{
    public static implicit operator BigInt(string value)
    {
        return new BigInt {Value = value};
    }
    public string Value { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't any way to do this in C# at this time.

Workarounds: You can check out [Nemerle](http://nemerle.org/About/) which is a very flexible, meta-programming friendly language based on the C# syntax.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to extend the language directly in the manner you describe.

You *could* write a .NET language that is C# like and accepts such a specifier, but there is nothing like what you are trying to do.

Note: There is an existing structure for integers of arbitrary size [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) - no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft already did this. It's called a BigInteger. Think it came out with .NET 4.0?

Here's the MSDN link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

As for extending it like that, I don't think that's possible in C#. You'd have to overload the assignment operator, and that's only do-able in C++ as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain but you can take a look at Roslyn. Check out http://kevinmontrose.com/2012/06/10/extending-type-inferencing-in-c/ for more information.